# get or post arguments causing `page not found` error in wordpress cutom template

Tags: php, wordpress

I created custom template using this code,

```
<?php /* Template Name: npg */ 
  echo "hello";
?>
```

And assigned this template to new page, When i open that page i can see `hello` printed there.

Issue is, when i pass variable in `get` like this

```
http://lh/folder/pagename?s=123
```

Getting page not found error.  But if i use like like this

```
http://lh/folder/pagename
```

I can see `hello`.

What is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you put the "?" character just after the pagename, without the "/" character ? Like this:

```
http://lh/folder/pagename?s=123
```

Comment: same issue, page not found